# How can I print the axis descriptions only once in a groupplot? (background: symbolic x coords breaks "xlabels at=bottom edge" option)

Tags: pgfplots, groupplots

I am using symbolic x coords in a groupplot. This proves problematic as I can't disable the ticks and tick labels for the upper plots without losing the `xmajorgrid`. I can't seem to find the appropriate option for this.

How can I disable only and only the tick labels for all plots but the ones in the last row? (in this case, only one plot/one column)

little note on the side to anyone following the pgfplots-tag: sorry for putting up so many questions, I seem to be extraordinarily cursed in this regards, i.e. to find many little things not working so well and not being able to think around the problems

### Picture

[image]

### MWE

```
\documentclass[
a4paper
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{
amsmath,
tikz,
pgfplots,
}

\usepgfplotslibrary{
groupplots,
}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\small]
\begin{groupplot}[
group style={
group size=1 by 3, %Spalte(n) by Zeile(n)
horizontal sep=0cm,
vertical sep=0.2cm,
xlabels at=edge bottom,
yticklabels at=edge bottom,
ylabels at=edge left,
yticklabels at=edge left,
},
%
ymin=0, ymax=30,
%
xlabel={Bla},
ylabel={Process},
%
xmajorgrids=true,
%
scale ticks above exponent={3},
]
\nextgroupplot[
xmin=10, xmax=20,
]
\addplot coordinates{(11,12) (13,15)};
\nextgroupplot[
symbolic x coords={11,13},
xtick=\empty,
]
\addplot[red, dashed] coordinates{(11,8) (13,25)};
\nextgroupplot[
xmin=10, xmax=20,
]
\addplot[orange, thick] coordinates{(11,8) (13,25)};
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you have a particular reason for using symbolic coordinates for this? They're really meant for categorical coordinates, and even then, I usually find that using `x expr=\coordindex` and `xticklabels={<list of labels>}` to work much better.

Comment: @Jake Thought it was simply the proper way to go about this. Admittedly my data is usually aligned be equal distances so... that's the catch.

Comment: @Jake Ah I don't even have to define `xticklabels=...` then. (Of course my Excel file has column headings so I write `x=Word` before `x expr=\coordindex`.) Your could post your comment as the solution then!

Comment: When using `x expr=\coordindex`, you also get equal distances between the data points.

Comment: How can I get an offset into the index? I have semi-categorical x coordinates {10,20,...100} and they always start at 20 although I specify them via `xticklabels={<list of labels>}`.

Comment: Have you set `xtick=data`?

Comment: @Jake Well I have now. :) Had it commented out for whatever reason, didn't remember that. Sometimes...

Answer (score 1):

### Workaround

The best remedy I found so far uses `x tick label style={color=white},`. It works pretty good, depending on the `xticklabel`s' position.

A significantly less satisfactory workaround is using something along the lines of `\draw[thin, gray] (rel axis cs:0.33,0) -- (rel axis cs:0.33,1);` to draw the grid and respective commands to draw the ticks. This might involve a lot of T&E runs.

```
\documentclass[
a4paper
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{
amsmath,
tikz,
pgfplots,
}

\usepgfplotslibrary{
groupplots,
}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\small]
\begin{groupplot}[
group style={
group size=1 by 3, %col(s) by row(s)
horizontal sep=0cm,
vertical sep=0.2cm,
xlabels at=edge bottom,
yticklabels at=edge bottom,
ylabels at=edge left,
yticklabels at=edge left,
},
%
ymin=0, ymax=30,
%
xlabel={Bla},
ylabel={Process},
%
xmajorgrids=true,
%
scale ticks above exponent={3},
]
\nextgroupplot[
xmin=10, xmax=20,
]
\addplot coordinates{(11,12) (13,15)};
\nextgroupplot[
symbolic x coords={11,13},
%xtick=\empty,
x tick label style={color=white}, %<-------------- WORKAROUND HERE
]
\addplot[red, dashed] coordinates{(11,8) (13,25)};
\nextgroupplot[
xmin=10, xmax=20,
]
\addplot[orange, thick] coordinates{(11,8) (13,25)};
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```